# Замена цифры в списке и проверка на её существование

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется список igrok = ['7', 'Q', '1'] Как мне перезаписать чтобы вместо 1 записывалась 10.
При том что цифра 1 может и не существовать в списке.
Хотелось бы получить вот такой список igrok = ['7', 'Q', '10']
Вся проблема заключается в том что 1(далее перезаписанная как 10) может оказаться в любом индексе. К примеру может быть так igrok = ['10', '7', 'Q']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень просто, можете пройтись циклом по списку и заменить значение методом `replace`:

```py
igrok = ['7', 'Q', '1']

for index, value in enumerate(igrok):
    if value == '1':
        igrok[index] = 10

print(igrok)
# ['7', 'Q', '10']
```

Comment: а что вернет `str.replace()` в случае, если нечего заменять?

Comment: Если Вы имеете ввиду такой список `['7', 'Q', '5']`, то вернёт тот же самый список, без изменений

Comment: да, но для такого списка ` ['7', 'Q', '10'] ` этот код возвращает ` ['7', 'Q', '100'] `

Comment: @SergFSM да, Вы правы. Обновил ответ :)

Answer (score 1):

```
igrok = [i if i != '1' else '10' for i in igrok]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.

Comment: 1. бежим по списку: .....  for i in igrok

Comment: 2. если элемент списка != '1' => оставляем, 
если == '1', меняем на "10" 
 .... i if i != '1' else '10'   .....

Comment: дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

могу предложить такой вариант, без цикла, но с использованием библиотеки pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

igrok = ['7', 'Q', '1', '11', '100', '10','1']
igrok = pd.Series(igrok).replace('1','10').to_list()  # ['7', 'Q', '10', '11', '100', '10', '10']
```